# Trying to use a select value to save information

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I used a select dropdown that is filled dynamically, based on conditions on country>state. But I can not get it out on context for the backend to properly save it to the database (selected value).

I can show the dropdowns correctly and save differently and correctly if I use a asp dropdownlist. Thing is, this code is imported and apparently all I can use if the select value.

```
<label for="country" class="col-form-label">Country:  </label>
                        <select name="txtAddress_Country" class="countries order-alpha form-control" id="txtAddress_Country" runat="server">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="txtPersonal_FirstName" class="col-form-label">State:  </label>
```

In the backend... this function works wonders with dropdownlist and text.

```
dbCampos.Save(u, new ASF.HC.JobApplication.Entity.Campo("txtAddress_Country", txtAddress_Country.Text));
```

So I am guessing the place to modify is the frontend.

I am guessing that I am missing some attribute but can not seem to find it. Says that it does not contain a definition for "Text" or accepting a first argument.

Maybe an initial value?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use  instead of html  with runat server.
secondly you can try as below:

```
dbCampos.Save(u, new ASF.HC.JobApplication.Entity.Campo("txtAddress_Country", txtAddress_Country.SelectedValue));
```

instead of:

```
dbCampos.Save(u, new ASF.HC.JobApplication.Entity.Campo("txtAddress_Country", txtAddress_Country.Text));
```